# Category URL path is a 404 when using category name in URL path

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

My Magento store is setup with my product category titled '**Technology'.**
There are several subcategories that display static blocks only. The URL path to the subcategories should be **/technology/subcat1/subcat2.**

However, this URL is a 404.  If I use **/products/subcat1/subcat2** it works.
Essentially, when I use a subcategory in the **'Technology'** category, I cannot use technology in the URL or links. The only path that will work is **'products'.**
When debugging the **url_path** for my categories contains products even though the category in the admin is titled **'technology'.**

> I've tried clearing cache, indexes (even though url_rewrite indexes are handled differently in M2), adding URL rewrites in the admin, etc. Nothing seems to be working.
>
> The **'Use Web Server Rewrites'** config setting is set to **'Yes'.**

Comment: you have to use www.domainname.com/technology/html.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. As I look into this more, I believe the issue stems from the magento data migration tool bringing over old/bad url_rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a result of using the data migration tool to migrate from M1 to M2

What I ended up doing was running the following MySQL commands to clear out all redirects for categories and products:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'url_path'; (This gives the attribute_id’s for the url_path for the next queries)
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id=47;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id=83;
TRUNCATE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE url_rewrite;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

At this point, all of the URLs for products and categories should be the SEO unfriendly versions. However, once a category is saved I see the correct entry in the catalog_category_entity_varchar database table. I used a tool(https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites) to regenerate all the product urls.

Answer (score 0):

change category url to some new value (add 1 in the end), save, then remove it. save.
reindex / clear cache